# Update labels on all pages if data changes

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm pretty new to `React Native`, so I'm unfamiliar with the terminology for what I'm looking for.

I have several pages where I show a label that's based on data I get from my API. On one page, I can update the value of this label, which I send to the API.

How can I automatically update the label values on all other pages? What's the term for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions. I'll list them in the following list:

- **State management**: Like Redux, Mobx, Zustand etc.
- **React Query**: The react-query is a powerful tool to handle asynchronous actions. If the change is a backend state, I *highly recommend* you use this. The previous item (state management) is still possible, but RQ is much better.
- **Context API**: The Context API provides a way to pass data through the component tree without manually passing props down at every level.